# Dropdown on image click in android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, drop-down-menu, android-drawable

Please go through the below image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od1BZ.jpg

I dont have any action bar and I made my custom header using below layouts which is shown in Figure-2

[Linearlayout]

[Relativelayout]

[linearlayout]

---

Back Button

App Icon

My APP text

Overflow Icon

---

[/Linearlayout]

[/Relativelayout]

[/linearlayout ]

now i need the dropdown like shown in Figure-1 on clicking overflow icon which is shown in red box on top right in Figure-2

how could i do this? I have tried spinner it giving me popup but i need just dropdown shown in Figure-1.

plz suggest me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all create a function or method in your java class file:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    MenuInflater menuINF= getMenuInflater();
    menuINF.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;

    }
@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case R.id.***:
       break;
       }
```

And add menu content by adding menu folder in res folder and create menu.xml in that folder (res->menu->menu.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_add" android:title="Add" android:icon="@drawable/icon"/>
<item android:id="@+id/menu_DashBoard" android:title="DashBoard" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_Master_Entry" android:title="Master Entry" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_Product_Section" android:title="Product Section" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_Retailers_Orders" android:title="Retailers Orders" />
</menu>
```

This may help you Its works for me.

Comment: what if I have theme as NoActionBar? then this solution don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

For **list_popup.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="#44444d"
                 >      

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="text"
            android:textSize="18dp"   
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#999999"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="text1"
            android:textSize="18dp"   
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
             android:gravity="center"     
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#999999"
            />

           <TextView
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="text2"
            android:textSize="18dp"
               android:textColor="#FFFFFF"  
               android:gravity="center"              
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#999999"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="text3"
            android:textSize="18dp"
               android:textColor="#FFFFFF"  
               android:gravity="center"              
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#999999"
            />


</LinearLayout>
```

**java**

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);             
        final View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_popup, null);              
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,200,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

onClick.

```
show_options.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if(popupWindow.isShowing())
                    popupWindow.dismiss();                    
                else                
                    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(show_options, 50, 0);        
            }
        });
```

**show_options** is your **overflow icon image name**

Here is some example

http://rajeshandroiddeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-popupwindow-example-in-listview.html

http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/07/how-to-create-popup-window-in-android.html

Comment: thanks for your response the code u have given above was good but my requirement is dropdown shown in the following pic http://i.imgur.com/3WqhVCj.jpg can u help me that

Comment: @maghub just design that in `list_popup.xml` it will display.

Answer (score 1):

Use dialog ([Example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/))
And to place dialog to correct height and width use

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
        wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_RIGHT;
        BitmapDrawable bd=(BitmapDrawable) this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.urdrawable);//urdrawable is your top bar image
        int height=bd.getBitmap().getHeight();
        //int width=bd.getBitmap().getWidth();
        //wmlp.x = width;   //x position
        wmlp.y = height;   //y position
```